# Inequality with modulus

Tags: inequality

I would be glad if someone will help me to understand how to solve inequalities as the following one:
$$\vert 6-3x\vert+x \leq \vert x+2\vert$$

I remember that I need to see where the modulus is zeroing, which is $2$ and $-2$. It's kinda pathetic, but I don't how to move on from this.

Comment: You had the right idea. Now consider your equation in the three intervals created by your two separators $-2$ and $2$, that is to say in $]-\infty, -2]$, $]-2,2[$ and $[2, +\infty[$. In these intervals, the interior of the modulus has the same sign so you can get rid of then, multiplying what is inside by $-1$ if the interior is negative in the interval, and leaving them as is otherwise.

Comment: The general idea is that you remove the modulus by discriminating the case where the argument of the modulus is less or greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$|6-3x|=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}6-3x, &x\le2 \\ -6+3x, &x\ge2\end{cases}$$ and similarly 
$$|x+2|=\begin{cases}\phantom{-}x+2, &x\ge-2 \\ -x-2, &x\le-2\end{cases}$$ Now take $3$ cases, $x\le-2$, $-2\le x \le 2$ and $x\ge2$ and solve. At the end of each case, compare the result with the condition you started with in order to determine the answer.

---

For example, for $x\ge2$ you have that $$|6-3x|+x\le|2+x| \iff 6-3x+x\le x+2 \iff x\ge \frac{4}{3}$$ Now, $x\ge 2$ and $x\ge 4/3$ are both true when $x\ge 2$. Thus the first interval that satisfies the inequality is $[2, +\infty)$. Now repeat for the other 2 cases to determine all solutions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But doesn't 6-3x should be for x<=2 and -6+3x for x>=2? And as for example, it should be x=> 4/3. I did it as that: 6-3x+x<=x+2  means 6-2<=x-x+3x  means 4<=3x means x=>4/3. If I'm wrong, can u explain me why plz, 'cause it's eating my brain ffs

Comment: @revolldxyz Sorry, both are my mistakes! You are very right in both your observations :)! I corrected them!

Comment: Ok then, thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

As you've pointed out, one of the moduli zeroes out at each of $x=\pm 2.$

One approach you can take, then, is to consider three cases: $x<-2,$ $-2\le x<2,$ and $x\ge 2.$ See what happens to the left- and right-hand side in each case, then solve, bearing the restriction in mind (since there may appear to be solutions that are then ruled out by the restriction in each case).